# How can I extract numbers from a string and put them in multiple variables?

Tags: python, parsing

I am using python on a Raspberry Pi.
One of my function's argument will be a string containing an unknown amount of numbers.

I need to extract them all and put them in different variables.
I will then pass those variables as arguments to :

```
t.write(serial.to_byte([OtherVar1, OtherVar2, OtherVar3, EXTRACTEDVar1, EXTRACTEDVar2, EXTRACTEDVAR3, etc])
```

I have decided (but it can change upon recommendation) that the string will have the following format: `NUMBER,NUMBER,NUMBER...` each number is going to be separated by a `,`.

Additionnal difficulty: Each number represents a 16 bit value that has to be put in 2 separate bytes. (So 8 would give me `VAR1=0x00` and `VAR2=0x08`)

How can I extract them?
Is there a way to generate a undefined amount of variables in a loop?

For those familiar with MODBUS, I am trying to create the MODBUS function 16, Write Multiple Registers. And I don't know how to deal with the unknown amount of Data I have to send.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Use `re.findall()` with a regular expression that matches a number.

Comment: If you need an undefined number of variables, you use a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
# number is your string of numbers
splitted = numbers.split(',')
result = [(num[:2],num[2:]) for num in splitted]
```

Note that `result` contains tuples of `string`, then you will need to convert them to a number depending on which base you will use.